# Custom Authentication PAW Extension

Tags: paw-app

I was able to create an extension that will create the dynamic Authentication token I needed, but I get some warnings that I've created a self dependancy.  I was wondering if there is a way to change the ext type to an authentication one so that it does not have such issues.

Comment: That's probably because you're accessing the header you're currently inside of. Maybe instead of `request.headers['Some-Header']` try `request. getHeaderByName('Some-Header')`, this should fix your issue (this just processes the request headers, not all).

Comment: That solved the warnings I was receiving.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Micha's advice worked.  My Custom dynamic variable extension that generates an authentication header works and no longer generates warnings.